# Why does this jquery code not remove the li list item?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
$('#list li a').on('click', function(e) {
    var user_id = this.parentNode.id.replace('list_', '');
    var id = 'id=' + user_id;
    e.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "xxx.php",
        data: id,
        success: function() {
            $(this).parent().hide(); //the problem is here 
            $('.updateNumber').html(function() {
                return parseInt($(this).text(), 10) + 1;
            });
        }
    });
});
```

i think after the ajax call it cannot reconize the li list because of the (THIS) selector, its not referencing it correctly, thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct that within the Ajax callback `this` is not the clicked anchor. The following should work:

```
    $('#list li a').on('click', function(e) {

        var user_id = this.parentNode.id.replace('list_', '');
        var id = 'id=' + user_id;
        e.preventDefault();

        var $a = $(this);

        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "xxx.php",
        data: id,
        success: function(){
            $a.parent().hide();
            $('.updateNumber').html(function(){
               return parseInt($(this).text(),10)+1;
            });
        });
    });
```

Save a reference to the clicked link outside the `$.ajax()` call. The callback function has access to variables in its containing scope.

Answer (score 0):

You identified the problem correctly. Every function has its own `this` variable, and you can't reference a parent function's `this` without adding another variable or doing some other sort of fancy finagling.

Anyway, your problem is very easy to fix. First, add a variable set to the correct `this`

```
$('#list li a').on('click', function(e) { 
  var $this = $(this);
  //...
```

and then reference that variable instead:

```
 $this.parent().hide();
```